# How can I start my animation a few seconds in?

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have a WPF storyboard in my codebehind which runs with several color animations chained together. It works just fine, but in some scenarios I would like to be able to start the animation in the middle (e.g. 5 seconds into colorAnimation2) rather than always at the beginning. How would I go about this?

```
StoryBoard storyBoard = new StoryBoard;
// each animation runs for 10 seconds and starts 10 seconds after the previous one.
storyboard.Children.Add(colorAnimation1);
storyboard.Children.Add(colorAnimation2);
storyboard.Children.Add(colorAnimation3); 
storyBoard.Begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the Seek() method just after calling storyBoard.Begin() to jump along the timeline by the given timespan.

```
storyBoard.Seek(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```